# How do you make 1 button do multiple events with only ONE click?

Tags: c#, button, textbox

So I am trying to show some flags in my code, which are just textboxes or labels. How do I get them to show multiple flags at the same time without having to click my button 2 times?

The code below is a setup for a 8 bit register, with 8 bit input A, and 8 bit input B. I want to out put 8 bits, and want to show a flag for carry, if carry was used in addition, and overflow, if there is an overflow. The problem Im having is showing both overflow and carry flags at the same time, without having to click the button 2 times.

```
textBox29.Visible = false;
textBox30.Visible = false;
string registera, registerb;
registera = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox5.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text;
registerb = textBox26.Text + textBox25.Text + textBox24.Text + textBox23.Text + textBox22.Text + textBox21.Text + textBox20.Text + textBox19.Text;
int output = Convert.ToInt32(registera, 2);
int output2 = Convert.ToInt32(registerb, 2);
output = output + output2;
string binary = Convert.ToString(output, 2);

for (int i = 7; i >=1; i--)
{
    if (registera[i] == '1' && registerb[i] == '1')
    {

        Carryflag.Visible = true;
     }
}   


if (output == 0)
{
    textBox28.Visible = true;
}
else textBox28.Visible = false; 

if (output > 255)
{
    Carryflag.Visible = true;
}

if (textBox18.Text == "1")
{
    OverflowFlag.Visible = true;
}



binary = binary.PadLeft(9, '0');

textBox18.Text = binary[0].ToString();
textBox16.Text = binary[1].ToString();
textBox15.Text = binary[2].ToString();
textBox14.Text = binary[3].ToString();
textBox13.Text = binary[4].ToString();
textBox12.Text = binary[5].ToString();
textBox11.Text = binary[6].ToString();
textBox10.Text = binary[7].ToString();
textBox9.Text = binary[8].ToString();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Could you maybe simplify this example to only two or three text boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving:

```
 if (textBox18.Text == "1")
 {
    OverflowFlag.Visible = true;
 }
```

to immediately after

```
textBox18.Text = binary[0].ToString();
```